# Get records between two datetimes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have found below query in one of our existing  Stored Procedures. This query used to take records between two datetime values.

```
SELECT office
FROM   officebudget
WHERE  officeid = @officeid
       AND (
               (CONVERT(DATE, DateFrom) BETWEEN @wkstdate AND @wkenddate)
               OR (CONVERT(DATE, DateTo) BETWEEN @wkstdate AND @wkenddate));
```

I have re-written it as below,

```
SELECT office
FROM   officebudget
WHERE  officeid = @officeid
       AND (
               (
                   bkto.DateFrom >= @wkstdate
                   AND bkto.DateFrom <= @wkenddate
               )
               OR (bkto.DateTo >= @wkstdate
               AND bkto.DateTo <= @wkenddate)
           );
```

I got the same result for both cases. but i need to know in any of the scenarios where both of the above queries will produce
different results?

(P.S: DateFrom, DateTo, @Wkstdate, @Wkenddate are `datetime` fields)

Comment: Queries can produce different results when @wkstdate != '2015-09-30'

Comment: Sorry. It was a hardcoded value. Now i edited the question

Comment: Do `DateFrom` and `DateTo` have non-zero time components? If so, you're missing the conversions that the first query does to remove the time components (plus the conversions in the first query are currently broken - it's great being asked whether two queries do the same thing when one of them doesn't even compile)

Comment: yes it have non -zero components.

Comment: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) ;).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, `first query are currently broken`. To me everything seems to be correct there.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - last edit added the `)` that closes the second `CONVERT` call - previously it read as `CONVERT(DATE, DateTo BETWEEN @wkstdate AND @wkenddate` which won't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are refactoring your query to make it sargable and to use possible indexes on columns `DateFrom` and `DateTo`.

Those will not result in same results because your query will omit rows where date part of `wkenddate` equals datepart of `DateFrom` or `DateTo` column values. For example let's say `wkenddate = '20151005'` and your column `DateFrom = '20151005 15:30'`. First query will include this row since both dateparts are equal. And your second query will omit this row since `'20151005 15:30' > '20151005'`.

Consider these example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(d DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('20151001 10:30'),
('20151004 10:30'),
('20151005 10:30')

DECLARE @wkstdate DATE = '20151001', @wkenddate DATE = '20151005'

SELECT * FROM @t WHERE CAST(d AS DATE) BETWEEN @wkstdate AND @wkenddate
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE d >= @wkstdate AND d <= @wkenddate
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE d >= @wkstdate AND d < DATEADD(dd, 1, @wkenddate)
```

Outputs:

```
2015-10-01 10:30:00.000
2015-10-04 10:30:00.000
2015-10-05 10:30:00.000

2015-10-01 10:30:00.000
2015-10-04 10:30:00.000

2015-10-01 10:30:00.000
2015-10-04 10:30:00.000
2015-10-05 10:30:00.000
```

You should rewrite as:

```
SELECT office
FROM   officebudget
WHERE  officeid = @officeid
       AND (
               (
                   bkto.DateFrom >= @wkstdate
                   AND bkto.DateFrom < dateadd(dd, 1 , @wkenddate)
               )
               OR (bkto.DateTo >= @wkstdate
               AND bkto.DateTo < dateadd(dd, 1, @wkenddate))
           );
```

Comment: But  Wkenddate is checked with <= condition is it? So Does it check equal and less dates of Wkenddate ?

Comment: So, it is good to convert Datefrom and DateTo as Date before comparison?

Comment: No it is not good because first query will not use any index. You should not use calculations on columns when it is  possible to do without it. Query in the answer does what you want and benefits from using possible indexes on columns: `DateFrom` and `DateTo`.

Comment: Thanks I got it.  But, If I use Between instead of >=  & <= any change will occur?

Comment: @user5359841, I gave you 3 examples and shown the respected output whith their differences as well, with explanation why third one is preferable.

Comment: Yes thanks for that. So I assume Incase of date fields both between and <= & >= will bring same results.

Comment: @user5359841, yes, in case of date fields both will return same results.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first query, you use a function (CONVERT) on the filtered columns (FateFrom and DateTo), then the engine could not use the index on it if it exists and so the first query would tend to be slower.

In the second query, you have entered manually the date like this : `2015-09-30`.
It is better to enter it like this : `20150930` because this last form is not dependant of the region of the server, whereas the first form is.

Comment: I any of the cases both will return different result sets? (P.S : I have removed that hardcoded value)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it will give you different result, or worst NO result at all.

The reason why the old code has a `CONVERT` is , the developer want to assure that he is comparing the same exact datatype to be able to avoid errors or unexpected result. Please see my example below to further understand.

This one will return `FALSE` : something like give you different result.

```
    DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = GETDATE() --2015-10-05 16:15:54.780 , i used date today
    DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = '20151005'

    IF @date1 = @date2
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'TRUE'
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT 'FALSE'
```

And this one will return `TRUE`: something like give you same result

```
    DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
    DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE,'20151005')

    IF @date1 = @date2
            BEGIN
                SELECT 'TRUE'
            END
            ELSE
                SELECT 'FALSE'
```

Hope my sample helps you in analyzing the your codes, my advise is `CONVERT` it first before comparing the two dates for you to get the exact result.

Comment: I think the 1st query will return false :). Thanks for the suggesion

Comment: @user5359841, yup as i have said on my explanation :)